# How do I get a variable in the event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I get something from the for-loop in the event handler?

This json array

```
var elements = [ { "id": "#id1", "name": "text1" }, { "id": "#id2", "name": "text2" } ];
```

is passed to that function

```
function setHandlers(elements)  {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)  {
        $(document).on("focusout", elements[i].id, function() {

            alert(elements[i].id);     // doesn't work because 'element' isn't
                                       // defined.
        });                         
    }
}
```

How can I access elements without defining it outside the function?
EDIT: types should be elements

Comment: is it `types` or `elements`

Comment: Just use `this` inside the event handler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like that:

```
function setHandlers(elements)  {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)  {
        (function(i){
            $(document).on("focusout", elements[i].id, function() {
                alert(elements[i].id);
            });   
        })(i);                 
    }
}
```

You need an anonymous function to keep the *i* value in every loop. I.e. putting it in separate context fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the closure variable `i`. You can use it by using a local closure

```
function setHandlers(elements)  {
    $.each(types, function(idx, obj){
        $(document).on("focusout", obj.id, function() {
            alert(obj.id);     // doesn't work because 'element' isn't
            // defined.
        });                         
    })
}
```

Note: You are iterating `types`, is it a mistake?

Comment: Is there also a solution without jquery (i'm just interested!).

Comment: @user2737037 see the other answer